# CHARINDEX with SQL returns partial matches

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble with the following SQL query;

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE ID='510' AND CHARINDEX(requires,'Absolute Position Anchor') > 0
```

I've been using this code for a while but today it all of a sudden starts returning rows where the requires column only contains 'Position Anchor'. Has my query been wrong all along or might something have changed in my MS SQL server settings?

Comment: @ArthurFranz . . . If you use `like` instead, you won't have confusion with the order of the arguments:  `requires like `%Absolute Position Anchor%'`.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the syntax flipped:

```
CHARINDEX('string to find','string to look in')
```

Change to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE ID='510' AND CHARINDEX('Absolute Position Anchor',requires) > 0
```

Or use LIKE, as Gordon Linoff suggests:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE ID='510' AND requires LIKE '%Absolute Position Anchor%'
```

Comment: Geez I feel really dumb! The other times that I was using this it was always exact matches between the two, so my bad code worked. Thanks!

Comment: Don't feel bad, it's kind of counter-intuitive since SUBSTRING/LEFT/RIGHT/REPLACE all take the field to be acted upon as the first parameter.